# Как лучше реализовать список со множественными выделениями?

Tags: android, material-design, design, recyclerview.adapter

У меня есть список, элементы которого состоят из `textView` и `checkBox`, пользователь выбирает нужные элементы, нажимает кнопку готово и все выбранные элементы сохраняются в `sharedPrefences`. Если же пользователь заходит в это окно не в первый раз и в прошлый он выбрал какие то элементы, то эти выбранные ранее элементы должны быть в начале списка, а дальше должны быть оставшиеся элементы (все элементы в алфавитном порядке). Если убрать выделение с ранее выделенных элементов, то они должны плавно перейти вниз, либо к списку добавляется новый элемент. Причем сперва, при открытии окна, показываются только 10 элементов и нижний `footer`, при нажатии на который появляются остальные элементы. Также в этом списке нужно реализовать поиск элементов.
Сначала думал про `ListView`, но там нет анимации. Начал использовать `RecyclerView`, выделение элементов сохранял в `SparseBooleanArray`, но тут постоянно появляются какие то косяки при обновлении списка, когда вызываешь `notifyItemChanged` нет анимации и список может не правильно обновится, а если каждый раз вызывать `notifyItemInserted`, то тогда не будут обновляться другие элементы в списке.
Подскажите как все это мне лучше реализовать, в какую сторону двигаться?
**RecyclerViewAdapter**

```
class RVAdapterFilterSelect extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private static final int FOOTER_VIEW = 1;

private class NormalFilterViewHolder extends ViewHolder {

    NormalFilterViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textElements.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String text = textElements.getText().toString();
                int position = items.indexOf(text);

                if (position < numberAllocated) {
                    delete(text);
                    numberAllocated--;

                    if (text.compareTo(items.get(items.size()-1)) > 0) {
                        items.add("Leadtek"); //Добавляем следующий элемент с бд LIMIT items.size(), 1
                        isClick.append(items.size(), false);
                        notifyItemInserted(items.size());
                    } else if (text.compareTo(items.get(numberAllocated)) < 0) {
                        items.add(numberAllocated, text);
                        isClick.append(numberAllocated, false);
                        notifyItemInserted(numberAllocated);
                    } else {
                        int size = items.size() - 1;

                        for (int i = numberAllocated; i < size; i++) {
                            if ((text.compareTo(items.get(i)) > 0) && (text.compareTo(items.get(i + 1)) < 0)) {
                                items.add(i+1, text);
                                isClick.append(i+1, false);
                                notifyItemInserted(i+1);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    isClick.put(position, !isClick.valueAt(position));
                    notifyItemChanged(position);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

private class FooterFilterViewHolder extends ViewHolder {

    FooterFilterViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                notifyItemRemoved(items.size() + 1);

                isFooter = false;

                Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), "Good", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                items.add("Leadtek"); //Добавляем следующий элемент с бд LIMIT items.size(), 1
                notifyItemInserted(items.size());

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
}

private List<String> items;
private boolean isFooter;
private int numberAllocated;

private SparseBooleanArray isClick = new SparseBooleanArray();

RVAdapterFilterSelect(List<String> items) {
    this.items = items;
    this.isFooter = true;
    this.numberAllocated = 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        if (i < numberAllocated)
            isClick.append(i, true);
        else
            isClick.append(i, false);
    }
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v;

    if (viewType == FOOTER_VIEW) {
        v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_for_recycler_view_select_footer, parent, false);
        return (new FooterFilterViewHolder(v));
    }

    v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_for_recycler_view_activity_manuf_or_model, parent, false);
    return (new NormalFilterViewHolder(v));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    try {
        if (holder instanceof NormalFilterViewHolder) {
            NormalFilterViewHolder vh = (NormalFilterViewHolder) holder;

            vh.textElements.setText(items.get(position));

            vh.checkBox.setChecked(isClick.get(position));

            if (position < numberAllocated) {
                vh.checkBox.setChecked(isClick.get(position));
            } else {
                vh.checkBox.setChecked(isClick.get(position));

                if (position - numberAllocated == 0) {
                    if (numberAllocated != 0) {
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        params.setMargins(0, 50, 0, 0);
                        vh.rlMain.setLayoutParams(params);
                    }
                } else if (!isFooter) {
                    String c1 = String.valueOf(items.get(position).charAt(0)).toLowerCase();
                    String c2 = String.valueOf(items.get(position - 1).charAt(0)).toLowerCase();

                    if (c1.compareTo(c2) != 0) {
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        params.setMargins(0, 50, 0, 0);
                        vh.rlMain.setLayoutParams(params);
                    }
                }
             }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (isFooter)
        return (items.size() + 1);
    else
        return items.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == (getItemCount() - 1) && isFooter) {
        return FOOTER_VIEW;
    }

    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    RelativeLayout rlMain;
    TextView textElements;
    CheckBox checkBox;

    TextView filterMore;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        rlMain = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rlMain);
        textElements = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textElements);
        checkBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        filterMore = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fliterMore);
    }
}

private void delete(String text) {
    int position = items.indexOf(text);

    SparseBooleanArray tmp = isClick.clone();
    for (int i = position; i < tmp.size()-1; i++) {
        isClick.put(i, tmp.get(i + 1));
    }
    isClick.delete(tmp.size()-1);

    items.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
}
```

Вот, что у меня имеется на данный момент (на 4ой фотографии Asus отображается не правильно, так как он должен попасть в нижний отдел списка):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По картинкам тут не гадают, что не так. Приложите код адаптера и другой код, связанный с проблемой, чтобы был воспроизводимый пример

Comment: @pavlofff Добавил код адаптера

Comment: Использование БД вы не рассматриваете, это бы решило множество второстепенных проблем? А такая БД, как Realm имеет свой адаптер для RecyclerView с уже реализованными анимациями и автообновлением при изменении в данных, что позволило бы реализовать почти все задание без дополнительного клиентского кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю реализацию с использованием базы данных [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/) по причинам, изложенным [в комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/647990/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8?noredirect=1#comment927806_647990) к вопросу.

Сначала, то что получилось в итоге:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь о реализации. Кнопка "Принять изменения" нам не понадобится, так как данные сразу сохраняются в БД и не будут утрачены при закрытии, без каких то дополнительных действий. Кнопку "Показать еще" я вынес из адаптера в низ активити, так как там, по моему скромному мнению, ей гораздо более лучшее место.

Начинаем с того, что [подключаем библиотеку Realm](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#installation) в свой проект, прописываем зависимости.

Добавляем зависимости адаптера Realm, ConstraintLayout и библиотек поддержки:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
}
```

Затем инициализируем БД в своем приложении:

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Realm.init(this);
        RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
    }
}
```

В манифесте указываем на переопределенный класс Application:

```
<application
    android:name=".App"
     ... >
```

Создаем класс-модель для БД:

```
public class Company extends RealmObject {

    String name;
    boolean isCheck;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isCheck() {
        return isCheck;
    }

    public void setCheck(boolean check) {
        isCheck = check;
    }
}
```

Теперь разметка активити и код этой активити.

activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="More Items"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

В запросе данных из БД производится сортировка по двум полям. При изменениях в адаптере (нажатиях чекбоксов) этот запрос будет повторятся и данные будут постоянно отсортированы в нужной последовательности. Нажатие на кнопку раскроет весь список.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    CompanyAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // на одном устройстве эта проверка не сработала и данные в БД не попали (список пустой)
        // в таком случае просто запустить метод initDB() один раз и закомментировать
        // иначе каждый запуск этого метода при отладке будет дублировать данные
        if (!(new File(realm.getConfiguration().getPath()).exists())) initDB();

        RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
        adapter = new CompanyAdapter(realm.where(Company.class).findAll().sort("isCheck", Sort.DESCENDING, "name", Sort.ASCENDING));
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               adapter.moreItems();

            }
        });
    }

    protected  void initDB (){
        final String names[] = {"ASUS","Gigabite","KFA2","MSI","Inno3D","Palit","EVGA","ZOTAC","PowerColor","Sapphire","HIS","Manli","AMD","Nvidia"};
        final Company company = new Company();

        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    for ( int i = 0 ; i < names.length; i++){
                        company.setName(names[i]);
                        realm.insert(company);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
}
```

Теперь создаем разметку айтема, естественно, что набросана она лишь бы работало и вы можете сделать гораздо ровнее и красивее. Основной момент здесь - скрытый сепаратор, который будет отделять чекнутые позиции от не чекнутых.

item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/check"
        tools:text="company" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

код адаптера. Здесь не обошлось без пары костылей, связанных с сепаратором. Дело в том, что его перемещение - нетривиальная задача, если нельзя обновлять адаптер (а тогда не будет анимаций), поэтому я просто поставил задержку, вы можете попробовать придумать более элегантное решение, на которое у меня уже не хватает времени:

```
public class CompanyAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<Company, CompanyAdapter.Holder> {

    private Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    private int size; // start item counters

    public CompanyAdapter(OrderedRealmCollection data) {
        // второй аргумент (true) - автоапдейт адаптера при изменениях данных
        super(data, true);

        size = (data.size() > 7) ? 8 : data.size(); //при старте выводить 8 первых позиций
    }

    @Override
    public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        return new Holder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Holder holder, int position) {
        final Company item = getItem(position);

        holder.name.setText(item.getName());
        holder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null); // fix IllegalStateException on scroll
        holder.check.setChecked(item.isCheck());
        holder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, final boolean isChecked) {
                realm.beginTransaction();
                item.setCheck(isChecked);
                realm.commitTransaction();
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, 350);
            }
        });
        if (position == getSeparatorPosition()) holder.separator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         else holder.separator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return size;
    }

    public void moreItems() {
        size = getData().size();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private int getSeparatorPosition(){
        int position = -1;
        boolean first = getItem(0).isCheck();
        if (first) {
        for (int i = 1; i < getItemCount(); i++){
            if (!getItem(i).isCheck()){
                position = i;
                break;
             }

        }
        }
        return position;
    }

    class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        CheckBox check;
        View separator;

        public Holder(View view) {
            super(view);

            name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            check = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
            separator = view.findViewById(R.id.separator);
        }
    }
}
```