# Создание БД realm для android

Tags: android, sql, realm

Учу сейчас андроид и дабы по практиковаться решил сделать приложение для универа. Один из функционалов - поиск аудитории. У меня есть список всех аудиторий, но мне надо сделать из них БД, что бы потом с помощью Realm считать данные. Но как сделать такую БД, найти никак не могу. Что для этого надо или как делать? Буду рад любой помощи!) Спасибо)

Comment: Что именно из доки реалма вам непонятно?

Comment: Мне нужно с 0 сделать свою БД для реалма вне приложения, а потом его туда впихнуть. Для Mac есть Realm Browser, но у меня Винда и что то ничего похожего не нашёл.

Comment: Может вам sqlite попробовать? Для windows есть бесплатные редакторы, в android studio работа с ней доступна "из коробки". Туториалов в сети много.

Comment: @НикитаШаврин, если у вас есть уже готовые данные, то можно просто их в ресурсы поместить и при старте приложения, проверив, что их нет из ресурсов достать и в БД положить. Если вас это не устраивает - опишите подробнее вашу задачу.

Comment: для Windows нет менеджера этой базы(в разработке, обещают скорый релиз уже больше года). Только для Mac и Android. Либо использовать эти ОС, либо заполнять программно, в самом приложении, [как здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/649328/177345)(`MainActivity` метод `initDB()`).

Comment: @pavlofff да у меня там просто более 400 значений. Писать это всё в самом проекте ну не торт. 
Я взял DB Browser for SQLite. Сейчас пытаюсь впихнуть в свой проект

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Учитывая что нет софта для создания БД Realm на Винду, сделал БД SQLite с помощью DB Browser for SQLite.